# Apache mod rewrite to block xhr requests

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I've observed that xhr requests getting redirected to oauth servers is a bad thing (b/c it's a robot and it can't respond to the request). It also seems that responses responses meant for people and therefore a redirect look like this:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

and a request that I want to fail (give a 407, but really a 403 will do just fine as well) looks like this:

```
Accept:*/* (star slash star)
```

So, what I want to do is redirect the first header accept and 407 (or 403 if that's easier) the second one. I write a rule and it seems to do the opposite of what I'd expect:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} ^(text/html+)$
   RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

this allows me to go through but if I stick a ! in front of the caret like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} !^(text/html+)$
```

it gives me a forbidden (403). My expectation is that the rule on bottom would allow me in since I have the text/html in my Accept and the second one shouldn't. However, what I'm observing is that the rule on top lets me through and the one on the bottom is throwing a 403. Is my understanding backwards or is this not the correct way to solve it? Ubuntu 15.10, Apache 2.4.12

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, my understanding was backwards. It's probably not a great question either. Essentially the rule that is working, the one on top

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} ^(text/html+)$
```

is saying: Match this expression. If I stick an ! or Not in front of it, of course it's going to ignore everything w/ text/html in it.